Whether Firebase Exception in Try-Catch Can Be Auto-Reported or Manually Reported？
In the process of Firebase log collection, when an Exception is caught in a try-catch block, can it be reported automatically? Or is it necessary to manually call the API method to report it?
Are there any methods to directly listen to and report the errors caught in the catch block?

You have to send it and it will show in Crashlytics as event type "Non-fatals"
You can read more about it here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android#log-excepts
Here is the code:
Kotlin
try {

   //your code here

} catch (e: Exception) {      
   FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e)
}

Java
try {

   // your code

} catch (Exception e) {
   FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
}


Firebase Crashlytics doesn't automatically report exceptions caught in a try-catch block. You need to log the error to Firebase manually using the API.
For example, inside a catch block:
try {
  // Some code that might throw an exception
} catch (error) {
  firebase.crashlytics().recordError(error);
}

Firebase will automatically capture uncaught exceptions and crashes, but you must explicitly report caught exceptions using recordError() or log().
